# Paypal Curl redirecting Issue

Tags: php, curl, paypal

This is regarding paypal through Curl. I am trying to access paypal by using below code. The code is working fine in one server. After moving this code to live server, getting the below error. Can anybody tell me the solution for this.

```
     $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
     $version = urlencode('76.0');
     $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Error:

> SetExpressCheckout failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (35)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`?

Comment: @Paypa_Robert, Thanks for ur response. just now I tried with the above code. Still not working. same error

Comment: Make sure you've got up-to-date openssl or gnutls libs installed. Can you run a `curl -v https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` and include the output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

I inserted this line in my code

Did you try this alternative ?